# session destroyed on mobile Google Chrome while changing view to desktop site

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I am using Google Chrome on a mobile device. When I change the mobile view to desktop view, the session is destroyed and it sends me to the login page of my website.

I am changing the view for my admin dashboard as some listing page is not showing properly in mobile view so I'd like to change to desktop view to be able to use the page properly.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: That's probably how it has to work, in case the site sets some sort of cookie that says "this is a mobile user, show them the mobile site".

Comment: Try disabling [`session.use_strict_mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) in your `php.ini`. If I recall correctly this setting takes into account the browser's user agent when validating the session. I experienced this issue with IE because it can randomly switch to compatibility mode which would invalidate sessions just by visiting a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is resetting session id on changing the view from mobile view to desktop or vice versa. To disable the resetting the session we have to disable the matching user agent. I have disabled in the CodeIgniter by `$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;`